# I cant figure out how to connect the tooltip I created to an image map.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cant figure out how to connect my custom tooltip I created to an image map. Basically, I don't know what to put in my area tags to call the tooltip function. Everything I have tried either doesn't work, or it shows up in the default tooltip. I have created an example on jsFiddle if someone wants to check it out. All help would be very appreciated!

Here is the example, http://jsfiddle.net/edocurug15/yNAsy/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Tooltips
$(".tip_trigger").hover(function () {
    tip = $(this).find('.tip');
    tip.show(); //Show tooltip
}, function () {
    tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip        
}).mousemove(function (e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20;
    var mousey = e.pageY + 20;
    var tipWidth = tip.width();
    var tipHeight = tip.height();

area title="This is the left eye" shape="rect" coords="373,365,404,402" href="#"
```

What do I put in my area tags to display the tooltip???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the event target to get the text from the area that triggered the event.

```
$(".tip_trigger").hover(function (e) {
    tip = $(this).find('.tip');
    var tipText = $(e.target).attr('title');
    tip.html(tipText);
    tip.show(); //Show tooltip
}
```

See this updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yNAsy/3/

Answer (score 0):

There is some code missing in your fiddle (e.g. example.js and the element with class "tip").
You should use the hover (mouseenter, mouseleave) event with the areas and copy the title attribute into your element with the class "tip".

```
$("area").hover(function () {
    console.log("hover");
    $(".tip").html($(this).attr("title"));
}
```

Comment: Hmm I sort of get what you mean. Would you mind editing the fiddle or showing me here what you mean?